# Adding dynamic Row Field in HTML in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to develop a functionality where I can add dynamic fields to a form. Now this is going to replicate an existing field and then replicate it. Here is the code

```
/**
* This function is used to dynamically add or remove rows from an unordered List
**/
//For Dynamically Adding and Deleting the rows and columns
$('.addRow').click(function (e) {

    // This gets the number of textboxes
    var curMaxInput = $(this).closest('ul').find('input:text').length;

    //Clones the first row.
    var html = $(this).closest('ul').first().clone(true);

    //for every textbox the 
    html.find('input:text').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('name') + '[' + (curMaxInput++) + ']');            
    });

    //Converting the '+' sign to '-' 
    html.find('span').removeClass('addRow').removeClass('ui-icon-plus').addClass('ui-icon-minus').addClass('removeRow');

    //Adding the onClick event to remove this row
    html.find('span').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        return false;
    });

    // appending the html to the list and thus making it dynamic
    $(this).closest('ul').append(html.find('li').first());

    //avoiding Post backs if any
    return false;
});
```

​

I'm able to replicate it but I'm able to clone the event and attach it to the new dynamic row field generated. But now when i'm trying to delete the copy, it does not delete.
Please let me know if you need more information on it.
Here is the jsfiddler link just in case you guys need more info 
[http://http://jsfiddle.net/jshah11/QavKj/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/jshah11/QavKj/3/)

I have updated the function according to the comments and I have updated the jsfiddler with it

Comment: Could you put what you have here in a jsfiddle

Comment: here is the jsfiddle link for the code http://jsfiddle.net/jshah11/QavKj/

Comment: So, currently, when you click the + it clones the first text fields (including any text the users may have input into the field). You want it that when the user clicks the new + sign (on the second set of text fields) it clones those text fields (not the first). Correct?

Comment: Change .clone() to .clone(true) to copy the events attached to the cloned element. See http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Thanks Jay. It worked. Now it has copied all the events with it.

Comment: Now it is copying the event but when I try to delete that row it does not delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for all the help. I am able to develop the functionality. Here is the Function which can be used to add dynamic row fields and remove them.

```
/**
 * This function is used to dynamically add or remove rows from a un-ordered List
 **/
//For Dynamically Adding and Deleting the rows and columns
$('.addRow').click(function(e) {

// This gets the number of textboxes
var curMaxInput = $(this).closest('ul').find('input:text').length;

//Clones the first row.
var html = $(this).closest('ul').first().clone(true);

//for every textbox the 
html.find('input:text').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('name') + '[' + (curMaxInput++) + ']');
});

//Converting the '+' sign to '-' 
html.find('span').removeClass('addRow').removeClass('ui-icon-plus').addClass('ui-icon-minus').addClass('removeRow');

//Turn off the current event
html.find('span').off('click');

//Adding the onClick event to remove this row
html.find('span').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
});

// appending the html to the list and thus making it dynamic
$(this).closest('ul').append(html.find('li').first());

//avoiding Post backs if any
 return false;
});​
```

Here is the jsFiddler link for your references for this function
http://jsfiddle.net/jshah11/QavKj/4/

Thanks again.